# Finding an equation for the cooling curve of water with respect to surrounding temperature

Tags: water, cooling

I would like to find a general equation that describes the cooling curve of water from 100 degrees Celsius to the surrounding temperature $T_s$ against time (say, in seconds). As far as I know and expect, the cooling curve should be sort of negative exponential shape and flats out at $T_s$. But is there a well-known equation about it? Thanks!

**Edit:** After reading the first comment below, I believe I need to make my question more specific. The water concerned is not held inside a container, it is just a patch of water spread on the tiled floor in a bathroom.

Comment: You are looking for Newton's law of cooling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling

Comment: Thanks for the link, when I read it I found that my question needs to be more specific. For example the surface area of water and the volume of water, and whether the water is held inside a container, and the materials of the container, can affect the result.

Comment: Yes, which is why there is no simple theory of cooling. Newton's law is a first order approximation assuming a constant heat transfer coefficient and "linear transport theory" (in modern nomenclature). If you look at the data sheets of industrial products like heat exchangers and heat-sinks, you will find measured performance curves that show the actual heat transfer as a function of temperature difference, air pressure, air flow velocity or volume, humidity etc., depending on application!